# eView the quotient topology of The real line $\mathbb{R}$ with $[-1,1]$ collapsed to a point.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

> $(e)$ The real line $\mathbb{R}$ with $[-1,1]$ collapsed to a point.

> $(f)$ The real line $\mathbb{R}$ with $[-2,-1] \cup [1,2] $ collapsed to a point.

My answer for the first case is  the same Real line because if I collapse the interval $[-1,1]$ i transfer it in a sigle point,and each diferent element is identify with their own equivalence class.

In the second case the result is a Circle with a line. the shape is like a Lollipop, the reason is i start with a line and when I begin with points of  $[-2,-1] \cup [1,2] $  the interval $(-1,1)$ is the loop thatforms the lollipop, next when I leave of these inteval I can take other trajectory that don´t intersect the the circle and my first line that I draw
Are my interpretations about the quotient right?
Any help, hint or recomendation was very helpful

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave justifications/explanations for the answers you give. In particular, what version of  "a circle with a line" are you imagining for (f)? Something that looks like a lollipop? Something that looks like a $\theta$? Something else?

Comment: Your answer for the first one is definitely wrong, but since you’ve not explained your reasoning, there’s no way to tell just where and how you went astray.

Comment: My justification are  if i glue all the points in the inetrval $[-1,1]$  I´m Identify all the points in one unique point, in it way when I recorre a trajectori  with two glue point I,m Do a loop, for example if i had the interval $[0,4]$ and I identify the integer points i get 4 petals  of one flower with center in one point which is the clase that contains $ \lbrace  0,1,2,3,4\rbrace$

Comment: I´m Edit my answer

Comment: I think $(a,-1]$ and $[1,b)$ become open sets in the first case

Comment: For the moment I don´t Know what are the definition of "collapse" a set in a point,I Only know the intuitive idea about if I collapse a set in a point then the set becomes a point in the quotient topology.